# UIWebView won't load new request

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, reload

It seems no matter what I do, I can't get my UIWebView to load a new URL. It receives the load request, but nothing I do seems to actually make it do anything.

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    urlToVisit = [self.arrayOfURLs objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    [WebViewToViewData loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlToVisit]]];
    //[WebViewToViewData stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"location.href='%@''",urlToVisit]];
}
```

as you can see, I have it loading the URL from a string (this is for testing purposes, but it doesn't work with anything) and it receives the request, but doesn't start loading. I've tried:

```
[WebViewToViewData reload];
```

and that doesn't do anything. I can't even get the reload function to work anywhere. What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had it set to a Modal Window and what I ended up doing is changing the Modal window to a different animation so that it would fire viewDidAppear and have the function in there. As for sending the values back and forth and I used a NSUserDefaults.

This was by far the silliest error I've had.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to check whether the url string contains space or other escape strings and convert them to percentage strings.

Comment: I have already checked that and I have no spaces or escape strings. It is just a URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
urlToVisit = [self.arrayOfURLs objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

[WebViewToViewData loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlToVisit]]];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

If that does'nt load, try simple url like http://www.google.com/ directly instead of taking strings from Array convert to URL and loading into webView.

Comment: I should have explained this earlier, and I'm sorry about that. The modal window is just displaying a table and the webView is in the main  view controller.

I did try what you recommended and it's still not loading anything, even with @"http://www.google.com" instead of the array

Answer (score 0):

I thing you need to define a protocol to load webview. Assuming that you present a view controller from main view controller which has the webview. In the second view controller you only have a table view. You are trying to load url on webview in mainview controller from second controller. If all these assumptions are true, you have to use protocol decleration for that.

Also you can try this

in second view controller .h file

```
id delegate;

@property(assign)id delegate;
```

in .m

```
@synthesize delegate;


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath


{


urlToVisit = [self.arrayOfURLs objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];



[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


[(id)delegate performSelector:@selector(loadHTML:) withObject:[NSURL URLWithString:urlToVisit]];


[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];



}
```

in first view controller implement,

```
-(void)loadHTML:(NSURL *) url{


[WebViewToViewData loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];


}
```

Comment: They are in the same view controller

Comment: so wont your webview dismiss after calling [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated]; because it is in same view controller?

Comment: I really don't know. I'm new to iOS programming. I'm converting the table to its own view controller now. Do you think that's the issue?
I can see the UIWebView after it gets dismissed and can click buttons and everything still. The WebView just doesn't load a new page.

Comment: usually it will dismiss the current viewcontroller. You just create new tableviewcontroller after main view controller. main view cllr contain webview. set delegate before u cal [self presentviewcontroller:table animated];

Comment: I did the way shown above, I added a view controller as well. It works just as before though. The UIWebView is refusing to load a new page.